# How to register Indian rupee sign in itext pdf generated by html

Tags: java, pdf

i'm using following code to generate pdf by html but the rupee symbol is not showing.

I can see rupee sign in html but not in pdf file.

```
Document document = new Document();
writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("pdf path"));
FileReader reader = new FileReader("html path");
document.open();

XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, reader);
document.close();
```

Please help me.

Answer (score -1):

You can use like this

This function returns string then you can put it into your PDF

```
public static String formatter(Double rupee){
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("\u20B9 000");
        return formatter.format(rupee);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException, IOException {
        System.out.println(formater(5000.00));
    }
```

Comment: How to do it while converting html to pdf?